# Distributing Twitter Widget Among Application Users

Tags: search, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

Hey guys is there anyway to circumvent the Twitter rate limit by using a Twitter widget and embedding it in the end users browser? In other words would using Twitter Search widget apart of the user's browser's session (while they are using my app) so that their calls to Twitter are made through their IP address (and not the IP address of my app) - I would do this to avoid getting the IP of my app blacklisted. Is that fine or would that violate Twitter's terms of use?

I would use the Twitter search widget. Would using Twitter stream be a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your implementation, you may want to consider the Streaming API for this purpose. It's probably considered more "kosher". You can query for a particular set of phrases and open whats called a firehose, and Twitter will push updates to your application and it's not really bound by rate limits although there is a rate limit system in place here. For my particular use case, this didn't work and I had to do what you described in your question. But if you want to use the Twitter streaming API and are using PHP in conjunction, I would highly recommend looking at the [140 Twitter Server framework](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/) at the start. It will make it a lot easier to implement the streaming API at the get go.

Comment: It seems that Twitter prefers that you use the streaming API versus the search API. I'm going to take a look at the 140dev site b/c he's using the streaming API. Thanks again, mate!

Comment: yvw , glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, and this is the solution I'm using. Use jQuery or something similar for the Ajax calls and send the response to the server for processing. The carry will be on each of the IP's that use your application. So, if that user is spamming Twitter with requests - they would get blacklisted, not your application.

Comment: Can you please go in further depth here? Does your response imply that the application you are referring to must be coming from the (spamming) user's browser or does the app have to be downloaded by the user?

Comment: I'll put it this way, what I'm trying to say is - if you create an application that has the user request the API through their client then their IP address is being bound by the rate limit. For example, if you write in code that has the end user request the API through Javascript. If your writing this requesting code portion server side, then your servers IP address is bound. You can use a creative mixture of the two, so the API request is made client side and sent server side to avoid the limits.